# is this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> code is correct

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a total newbie when it comes to mod_rewrite and RewriteEngine (i don't even know how its called.)

Can you please take a look at this code and tell me if it is correct and if it works properly? Do i need to separate the https code from the other code or no?  Thank You.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: We cannot tell you if it works correctly, since we do not know what it is meant to do. You did not tell us.

Comment: sorry, i only know the first 3 rows are about he https redirect. the rest is something from wordpress. you think i should separate the https redirect code from the other code or no? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: well, the https redirect is working fine so i know for sure that works. But i dont know if the rest of the code is working properly... i don't even know what it's about :)

Comment: You cannot really "separate" that. And things look fine on first sight. Just one thing: you want to test if https is off, not for port 80 in your https redirection. Sure, _usually_ will come out the same, but why not use the correct check?

Comment: You don't know what "the rest of the code is about"? Then why do you use it? What for?

Comment: its something coming from wordpress :) i just wanted to add https redirect so i thought it's better to place it with the rest instead of making a new rewrite stuff. sorry i'm a newbie when it comes to these things

Comment: Looks fine to me. But the best test simply is to _use_ it. _Does it work_?

Comment: seems to work yes. One more question please. i want every page in my website to redirect to https. whats the better (correct) way to do it - with RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 or with RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on